# How can I slide in while visualising?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a invisible `div`.

```
<div id="some_div"
     style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
```

Now I can I slide it from right to left while making it visible? I mean from the left outside of the window to the absolute position?

I already succeeded sliding out some already visible elements.

```
some_other_div.toggle('slide', {direction: "right"});
```

And following code doesn't work.

```
some_div.toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'});
```

Comment: `visibility` is not valued in integers but some string values. So it can't be changed while any kind of animation. It will always have instantaneous action. Same is for `display`.

Thought you can make use of `opacity`. Initially set it `0` and then in animation stages move it towards `1`. It can have decimal values.

Comment: Please add code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Pankaj I believe I already put my codes that I've tried so far.

Comment: Alright, I try to frame an example around `opacity`

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know how jQuery functions work.

I'm sorry I didn't say that I'm a newbie on the front-end web application area.

I'm answering for my own question for others may have the same problem

I removed the `visibility` from the `style` attribute.

```
<div id="some_div"
     style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px;">
</div>
```

And the jQuery's `toggle` function started working.